Central AC - musty smell from ducts
Our HVAC is 4 years old. We ran the AC all summer with no problem. Then the weather got cool and we switched to heat for two weeks.
Now we’ve had a hot spell and put the AC back on. A strong musty smell is coming out of all the ducts.
We had an HVAC company come check it out, and they can’t find the source of the smell. The coils were very clean already.
Any ideas?

Welcome to DIY.SE! Try searching "musty smell in ducts" on DIY.SE's search function. This is a well-duplicated and answered problem. (A bit of Stack Exchange site usage: as you enter a question, SE automatically shows in a search box above the question box other questions that may be the same as yours, even before you post you question.)
